# Minimal django image uploader using the admin

Tags: django, image, admin, uploader

I'm working on my first project and I need a minimal image uploader using the admin that return the images in a html with their urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [django-attachments](https://github.com/bartTC/django-attachments).

Only your attachments will be image files. Also, it gives an URL to the attachment.